# If I accept an offer of admission to MSc in UK, can I later decline to accept another offer?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-kingdom

I have applied for a MSc in a UK university for the academic year 2017/18. I was offered an unconditional offer and I have to make a decision on it within 4 weeks and now two weeks have passed. But as I have not yet heard from other universities, I would like to take more time before accepting the offer. When I requested for more time to consider my decision the university informed me that **it is better to accept the offer as I can always decline it**.

But I would like to know whether there are any rules which state like I have an obligation to study at the university if I have accepted a place because if I get a place at another university which I am interested in, then I may drop this offer. Would the process allow me to decline the offer after accepting it, should I need to, and accept the offer at some other university?

I am not a student from UK, so if anyone can provide me guidance on this it would be helpful.

Comment: I am not based in the UK (hence the comment and not an answer) but I am pretty certain that nobody can force you to do a graduate program if you don't want to. So, you can always drop it. Although it might be frowned upon, since it would mean that they have to restart the recruitment process if you drop out.

Answer (score 2):

In some education systems there is something called the 'census date'. It is the date on which you would be considered committed to a course or program. Before the census date you can pull out with no strings attached. Call the Program Advisor, she or he will know the details, and you will not look bad for asking.